# C# unable to load embedded EXE after publish

Tags: c#, publish, embedded-resource, relative-path

I am integrating an EXE file into my C# desktop app (When I search my problem, results are related to web apps).

I used the following command to run it in debugging mode, and it just works fine.

```
Process exeProcess = Process.Start("Test.exe");
```

However, the problem arises when I want to publish the application:

```
 ************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

I added the exe file to project and set copy to output directory is on Copy always and the test.exe.deploy exist in the deployed application folder along with my database files but I still get the same error.

Since, I am using same method for my database:

```
|DataDirectory|\UserData.mdf
```

I tried this to run the exe with a relative path:

`string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
 string rel= Path.Combine(path, "test.exe");
 Process exeProcess = Process.Start(rel);`

But, still no luck!

What am I doing wrong? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Is the exe in the same folder as your app?  If so you could try: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.exe"`

Comment: I tried, but still get the same error. I even copied the test.exe to the  directory manually (even though it is .exe.deploy exist).

Or maybe I am doing something wrong in publishing it?